# The relation between street-aware routing in VANETs and V2V communication

Tags: routing

As known, RIVER protocol is a geographic, V2V, street-based protocol which relies on anchor points (intersection points). How can it detect these anchor points without resorting to fixed infrastructures (or RSUs)? Is V2V communication behind that?

Comment: You should read the seminal paper and discuss it with the author, James Bernsen. His paper and e-mail address at the University of Kentucky are freely available.